# Missing ) after argument list. What is missing from this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var formBody = [];
for (var property in submitLeadData) {
var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(`enter code here`submitLeadData[property]);
formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
}
formBody = formBody.join("&");

$.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: submitLeadData,
    success: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: submitBrokerLead,
            data: formBody,
            success: function(){
                alert(5);
            }


}

});
```

What is missing?

Comment: You should try to format your code clearly first.

Comment: Your dataType is weird. Remvoe it.

Comment: You are missing a `})` for the second `$.ajax({` You should look more closely at these type of problems before posting a question. They are usually pretty easy to solve by looking at documentation

Comment: You can use http://jshint.com/ to validate the syntax online.

Comment: Most editors will highlight the corresponding bracket when you move the cursor to one. This isn't a difficult problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You dont close your functions correctly in the lines given below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'post.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
  data: submitLeadData,
  success: function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: submitBrokerLead,
      data: formBody,
      success: function() {
        alert(5);
      }
    }); //add the bracket '(' and semi-colon ';' here
  } //add the curly bracket here
});
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping the corrected code, please also explain what you changed in the original code and why it solves the problem.

Comment: I decided to go ahead and 'help' you with the wording of your answer to make it obvious to the OP what the actual problem was

Comment: Thanks @MasterYoda